# How to get manipulation events to work on an element that contains a ScrollViewer child

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Say I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid ManipulationMode="TranslateY" ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" />
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" />
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" />
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

(The StackPanel is just arbitrary content.)

I would like the Grid to handle TranslateY manipulation events only, and the ScrollViewer to scroll horizontally only; however the ScrollViewer takes precedence even if the manipulation was vertical and not horizontal. The Grid never receives ManipulationDelta events, except if I disable scrolling on the ScrollViewer, which obviously isn't what I would like.

Does this have something to do with the ScrollViewer's "magical" behavior of direct manipulation events? I've tried different combinations of "rails" settings too (i.e. setting Grid's ManipulationMode to TranslateRailsY and setting IsHorizontalRailEnabled to true on the ScrollViewer) but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, parent elements of `ScrollViewer` won't receive the *manipulation* events as they are blocked by the *direct manipulation* events of the `ScrollViewer`.

However, elements **within** the `ScrollViewer` will be able to receive them as long as their `ManipulationMode` includes the `System` mode.

In your particular case, you will want to monitor the `ManipulationDelta` event on your `StackPanel` and have its `ManipulationMode` set to `TranslateY,System`.

Also don't forget to give your `StackPanel` a `Transparent` background for receiving events.

```
<StackPanel Background="Transparent" ManipulationMode="TranslateY,System" ManipulationDelta="StackPanel_ManipulationDelta">
```

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollViewer marks the manipulation event as handled, which causes it not to bubble up to the Grid. You have to change this behavior.

You can subscribe to the [ManipulationStarted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationstarted.aspx) event from the ScrollViewer. The documentation on that event should get you started.

Comment: `ScrollViewer` is `sealed` in UWP.